# Why does my window size change after loading my UI?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a kind of game like Google dinosaur. The problem is that when I start my application, the height of my window changes a few seconds later, so when I try to place the "dinosaur" at the bottom it remains floating, because the height of the window changed.

The "dinosaur" is the box that is floating:

[image: The "dinosaur" is the box that is floating]

This is the main window

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QFrame
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QBrush, QPainter
from PyQt5 import uic
import random

class animation(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.shapes = []
        self.dimension = 50

        #hilo del juego
        self.game_timer = QTimer(self)
        self.game_timer.timeout.connect(self.animation)
        self.game_timer.start(10)


        #crear las figuras
        self.shapes_generator_timer = QTimer(self)
        self.shapes_generator_timer.timeout.connect(self.new_shape)
        self.shapes_generator_timer.start(500)

        #jugador
        coord_x = self.width()
        coord_y = self.height() - self.dimension
        
        self.player = QRect(200, coord_y-2, self.dimension, self.dimension)

        

        
    def new_shape(self):
        coord_x = self.width()
        coord_y = self.height() - self.dimension
        
        rect = QRect(coord_x, coord_y-2, self.dimension, self.dimension)
        
        self.shapes.append(rect)

    

    def animation(self):
        for index,shape in enumerate(self.shapes):
            shape.moveLeft(shape.left() - 5)

            self.delete_shape(index,shape)
        self.update()
        print(self.height())

    def delete_shape(self, index,shape):

        if shape.getCoords()[2] < 0:
            del self.shapes[index]
            print(len(self.shapes))
        


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.white,0,Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.white,Qt.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())


        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black,1,Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.green,Qt.SolidPattern))
        for shape in self.shapes:
            painter.drawRect(shape)

        painter.drawRect(self.player)

    


ui, _ = uic.loadUiType("PYQT5\interface-animation.ui")

class MyApp(QWidget,ui):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        
        

        self.animation = animation()
        frame = self.findChild(QFrame, "frame")

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.animation)

        frame.setLayout(layout)
    

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myApp = MyApp()
myApp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And this is my UI file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1201</width>
    <height>638</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">background-color:rgb(0,0,0);</string>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot rely on the geometry of a widget within its instantiation, unless you specify a fixed size: by default all QWidget classes have a size of 640x480 during inizialitation.

In your case, the solution is simple: move the computation of the player position in the [`resizeEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent), which is the event that is received everytime a widget is being resized (by the system, the user, or any parent/child layout requirement):

```
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.player = QRect(200, self.height() - self.dimension-2, self.dimension, self.dimension)
```

Note that your implementation is not completely correct, as the result is that the obstacles will have a wrong position if the window is resized while playing, so I suggest another approach: always create items at y=0, and translate the rectangles in the paint event:

```
class animation(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.player = QRect(200, 0, self.dimension, self.dimension)

    def new_shape(self):
        coord_x = self.width()
        rect = QRect(coord_x, 0, self.dimension, self.dimension)
        self.shapes.append(rect)

    # ...
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)

        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.white,0,Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.white,Qt.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

        coord_y = self.height() - self.dimension

        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black,1,Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.green,Qt.SolidPattern))
        for shape in self.shapes:
            painter.drawRect(shape.translated(0, coord_y))

        painter.drawRect(self.player.translated(0, coord_y))
```

Please note that using `findChild` for a UI created with uic/pyuic is pointless, as the instance attributes for each widget are already created in the `setupUi`: you can already access the frame using `self.frame`:

```
class MyApp(QWidget,ui):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...

        self.frame.setLayout(layout)
```

You probably found out about that approach in some online tutorial, unfortunately they are completely **wrong** about that, and suggesting it is a very bad practice.